# Append a JSON string to a file which already contains JSON in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, formatting, append

I'm trying to append a JSON string into a file which has already more JSON strings:

```
[
    {
        "title": "A test title",
        "content": "A test content",
        "date": "10/01/10",
        "author": "zad0xsis",
        "id": "vnMiP"
    },
    {
        "title": "A test title",
        "content": "A test content",
        "date": "10/01/10",
        "author": "zad0xsis",
        "id": "vnZiP"
    },
    {
        "title": "A test title",
        "content": "A test content",
        "date": "10/01/10",
        "author": "zad0xsis",
        "id": "vnAiP"
    }
]
```

I'd need to append strings like `{"title":"test","content":"test","date":"2011-12-10 21:35:48 +0100","author":"zad0xsis","id":"0EhQ0"}` conserving the JSON format:

```
[
    {
        "title": "A test title",
        "content": "A test content",
        "date": "10/01/10",
        "author": "zad0xsis",
        "id": "vnMiP"
    },
    {
        "title": "A test title",
        "content": "A test content",
        "date": "10/01/10",
        "author": "zad0xsis",
        "id": "vnZiP"
    },
    {
        "title": "A test title",
        "content": "A test content",
        "date": "10/01/10",
        "author": "zad0xsis",
        "id": "vnAiP"
    },
    {"title":"test","content":"test","date":"2011-12-10 21:35:48 +0100","author":"zad0xsis","id":"0EhQ0"}
]
```

So it looks something like so, in little words, appending it so it's still valid JSON. How can I achieve this in Ruby? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the json gem, you could parse the file's content, add the new hash to the array and re-encode it into JSON to rewrite the file.